# How is the chain operator as defined in Griffiths "Consistent Quantum Theory" is a linear operator on the space of histories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-systems

on page 138 of Griffiths "Consistent Quantum Theory" (2004) he defines a chain operator $K$ s.t. $$K(F0*F1....Fn)=FnT(jn,jn-1)Fn-1....F1T(j1,j0)F0$$

Where $T$ is the unitary Time operator.

He claims that $K$ is linear on the space of histories.  How is this shown?